# Add Multiple values to a specific Key In a Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary

I have  6 Dictionaries where I am saving key1,value1 and Key1,Value2  depending on the conditions of plate, bowl or spoon.

Firstly I was saving different values in different Dictionaries, but now I want to save the values related to plates like : PlateID, color and value of the condition (100) for the key as name="plate1".

similarly for the bowl and spoon, I want to eliminate the last 3 dictionaries and use only the first 3 dictionaries to save these values.

**New Implementation of Class:**

```
abstract class Silver
{
    public double SilverId { get; set; }
    public double InnerTextValue { get; set; }
    public double Color { get; set; }
}

class PlateValues : Silver{ }
class BowlValues : Silver { }
class SpoonValues : Silver{ }
```

**Dictionaries:**

```
    private static IDictionary<string, Silver> plateValues = new Dictionary<string, Silver>();
    private static IDictionary<string, Silver> bowlValues = new Dictionary<string, Silver>();
    private static IDictionary<string, Silver> spoonValues = new Dictionary<string, Silver>();
```

I am adding values depending on the conditions as below: 
**C# Code**

```
        XmlDocument itemDoc = new XmlDocument();
        itemDoc.Load(@"C:/XML/sample.xml");
        Console.WriteLine("sample has {0} children.",
        itemDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Count);

        // iterate through top-level elements
        foreach (XmlNode CrockeryNode in itemDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            foreach(XmlNode silver in  CrockeryNode.ChildNodes)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode silvertypeNode in CrockeryNode .ChildNodes)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode childNodeAttributes in silvertypeNode )
                    {
                        XmlElement ruleElement = (XmlElement)silvertypeNode ;
                        //adding to list
                        manifestStatus.Add(ruleElement.Attributes["silverid"].Value);

                        foreach (XmlNode childNodeAttrib in childNodeAttributes.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            foreach (XmlNode childNodeConditions in childNodeAttrib.ChildNodes)
                            {
                                foreach (XmlNode childNodeCond in childNodeConditions.ChildNodes)

                                    if (childNodeCond.Name.ToUpper() == "CONDITION")
                                    {
                                        string[] temp = (childNodeAttrib.Attributes["name"].Value).Split(new Char[] { '.' });
                                        if (temp[0].Equals("plate"))
                                        {
                                            plateValues.Add(childNodeAttrib.Attributes["name"].Value,
                                            new PlateValues
                                            {
                                                 SilverId = Convert.ToDouble(ruleElement.Attributes["SilverId "].Value),
                                                 InnerTextValue = Convert.ToDouble(childNodeCond.InnerText),
                                                 Color= Convert.ToDouble(childNodeCond.Attributes["color"].Value)
                                            });

                                        }
                                        else if (temp[0].Equals("bowl"))
                                        {
                                            bowlValues.Add(childNodeAttrib.Attributes["name"].Value,
                                            new BowlValues
                                            {
                                                 SilverId = Convert.ToDouble(ruleElement.Attributes["SilverId "].Value),
                                                 InnerTextValue = Convert.ToDouble(childNodeCond.InnerText),
                                                 Color= Convert.ToDouble(childNodeCond.Attributes["color"].Value)
                                            });
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            spoonValues.Add(childNodeAttrib.Attributes["name"].Value,
                                            new SpoonValues
                                            {
                                                 SilverId = Convert.ToDouble(ruleElement.Attributes["SilverId "].Value),
                                                 InnerTextValue = Convert.ToDouble(childNodeCond.InnerText),
                                                 Color= Convert.ToDouble(childNodeCond.Attributes["color"].Value)
                                            });
                                        }
                                         break;
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

**Samle XML File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<crockery version="2" lastmodified="2015-08-06 03:53:06.207">
  <silver>
    <silvertype silverid="8504p" >
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="plate1" type="int">
                <conditions>
                    <condition type="shine" color="White">100</condition>   
                </conditions>
            </attribute>
            <attribute name="plate4" type="int">
                <conditions>
                    <condition type="shine" color="gold">87</condition> 
                </conditions>
            </attribute>

        </attributes>
    </silvertype>

    <silvertype silverid="3487s" >
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="spoon2" type="int">
                <conditions>
                    <condition type="shine" color="black">58</condition>    
                </conditions>
            </attribute>
            <attribute name="spoon6" type="int">
                <conditions>
                    <condition type="shine" color="gold">45</condition> 
                </conditions>
            </attribute>

        </attributes>
    </silvertype>

    <silvertype silverid="2398b" >
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="bowl7" type="int">
                <conditions>
                    <condition type="shine" color="black">8</condition> 
                </conditions>
            </attribute>
            <attribute name="bowl4" type="int">
                <conditions>
                    <condition type="shine" color="gold">45</condition> 
                </conditions>
            </attribute>    
        </attributes>
    </silvertype>
  </silver>
</crockery>
```

While Executing I get exception. 
[image]

I get the aboveexception at ***plateValues.Add(childNodeAt***

```
if (temp[0].Equals("plate"))
{
                                            plateValues.Add(childNodeAttrib.Attributes["name"].Value,
                                            new PlateValues
                                            {
                                                 SilverId = Convert.ToDouble(ruleElement.Attributes["SilverId "].Value),
                                                 InnerTextValue = Convert.ToDouble(childNodeCond.InnerText),
                                                 Color= Convert.ToDouble(childNodeCond.Attributes["color"].Value)
                                            });
}
```

Am I proceeding wrong?

Comment: Have you considered to create a type which contains all values and then add this to the dicitonary ? So something like Dictionary<string,MyValueClass> ?

Comment: @BoasEnkler yes, but I am not sure how that has to implemented. I have seen examples of tuples and keys but the class one seems better approach.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a structure as value

```
struct myStruct
{
    int value1, value2;
    string value3;
}

Dictionary<string,myStruct> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string,myStruct>();

myDictionary.Add("Key", new myStruct() {value1=12, ...});
```

Comment: You could also use a class, depending on how complex it becomes. Both will work :)

Comment: While absolutely correct solution I would not recommend anyone starting with `struct`. For many people behavior of struct (and especially mutable one as in example) is beyond understanding and will cause unnecessary problems (and it is unclear if there are any benefits for using `struct` in this case).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov if he just uses it to keep his data together and accesable by one key, I think he should not have any problems using a `struct`..

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, but I would set up a OOP hierarchy. This allows you to later add spoon-specific properties or methods:

```
abstract class Silver
{
    public double Id {get; set;}
    public double Value {get; set;}
}

class Plate : Silver {}
class Spoon : Silver {}
class Bowl : Silver {}
```

And since it looks like all your names are unique, you would only need one dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Silver> silvers = new Dictionary<string, Silver>();
```

And you can instantiate the various types as you go along. For example for a plate:

```
if (temp[0].Equals("plate"))
{
    silvers.Add(childNodeAttrib.Attributes["name"].Value,
        new Plate 
        {
            Id = Convert.ToDouble(ruleElement.Attributes["silverid"].Value),
            Value = Convert.ToDouble(childNodeCond.InnerText)
        });
}
```

Then if for example, you want to enumerate over only the plates, you can use `IEnumerable.OfType<T>`:

```
var myPlates = silvers.OfType<Plate>();
```

---

You could of course forgo the above and just use a simple `enum` to denote the `SilverType`:

```
enum SilverType { Plate, Spoon, Bowl }

class Silver
{
    public double Id {get; set;}
    public double Value {get; set;}
    public SilverType SilverType {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: : I have implemented the class code of yours but I get an exception. Post Edited for exception with image and line where it get Triggered.

Comment: So something is null, like there isn't a "color" attribute or something.

Comment: :         No, the color has a value as shown in the xml

Comment: I don't know; debug it and figure out what is null.